# Database to stop insert if is the same minute as previous insert? How?

Tags: php, mysql

Need little help with database and have this code:

```
    $result = mysql_query("select * from mydatabase"); 
 if ( ! mysql_num_rows($result)) { 

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mydatabase
```

"somedata" etc,...

How set this to stop if loaded on same minute as previous result inserted?

Comment: *"and have this code"* - That's it? Throw me a bone, at the very least.

Comment: @Fred -ii Of course it is only part of my code.

Comment: You'll need to query using date/time functions. MySQL has many to choose from.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Yes, I know also there must be some extra PHP code for it, am I right? :)

Comment: Google.com better to look there, here is nobody whiling to help.

Comment: A minute field of some sort in the table with a `unique` contraint.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @developerwjk that may be awesome idea, how to do it, please explain me more (I never doin that, thanks!).

Comment: assuming you create the table with sql like `create table ...` put the word `unique` at the end of the line for that field.

Comment: @developerwjk It cannot be done, as I explained bellow, but thanks, anyway.

Comment: In that case I'm voting to close as too broad. The fact is you can do it. If the table is already created, all you have to do is clear out any duplication on that field and do an `alter table` to set the field as `unique`. If for some reason you don't have enough access to the db to even do this, you should tell your boss you can't do your job because they tied your hands. If this is your own project, go to MySQL's website and look through the SQL specs because its a weak knowledge of SQL that's preventing you.

Comment: Also adding to the problem is your use of the old `mysql_` functions which don't provide good error handling.  Switch to PDO and then you can use try..catch and catch the violation of unique constraint error you need to catch when an insert fails due to the fact that it would cause duplication.

Comment: @developerwjk I can't do any unique parameter into database, I don't need it, because it will caused error in my script. I need only to limit insertion to one per minute.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to constrain this is to create a `UNIQUE` index on a column that's intended for this purpose. Usually dividing a [UNIX time value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) by 60 will yield a suitable minute index.

This can safely be stored in an `INT` type column. Then you can do a regular `INSERT` and if that fails due to a key conflict on that column you can ignore it. There's even the `INSERT IGNORE` option to do it automatically.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE by_minute (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  minute INT,
  UNIQUE KEY `index_by_minute_minute` (`minute`)
);

INSERT IGNORE INTO by_minute (name, minute) VALUES ('test1', 23730990);

INSERT IGNORE INTO by_minute (name, minute) VALUES ('test2', 23730990);

INSERT IGNORE INTO by_minute (name, minute) VALUES ('test3', 23730991);
```

That should only allow `test1` and `test2` rows to be inserted.

You can also use `FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) / 60)` in place of computed `minute` values.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, all this have to be done in MySQL, am I right?

Comment: When you're talking about data integrity, the correct place to do this is the database, yes. Application code can only give an assessment unless you commit to using transactions and locking, a very messy alternative.

Comment: I am sorry, but it will not work for me, I cannont manipulate here with  UNIQUE index - It must be done with PHP script which will send query to Database and see if is currently loaded one minute after and if is loaded the same minute, then must stop and exit.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here. Do you want to limit insertions to one per minute, or do you want to find out if something has been inserted within the last minute?